# What built in mechanism does SQL Server have to do Flashback Queries?

Tags: sql-server

Think that says it all?

Comment: Now that Sql Server has MVCC it should be trivial tho, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None.  SQL Server does not have an equivalent feature.

---

**UPDATE**: From SQL Server 2016 on, this information is outdated. See the comments and answers below.

Comment: Now that it has MVCC it's really surprising that it doesn't.

Comment: Incorrect - see Daniels [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49008221/470530) below - and check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @Vérace - Daniel's answer is for SQL 2016, this question was asked in 2009.  So at the time the question was asked/answered it was correct.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is quite old, but with **SQL Server 2016**, Temporal Tables is a feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables

Maybe it can help others in case they come to this topic (Searching for something similar to Oracle Flashback feature)

With temporal tables enabled, you can query table AS OF a specific timestamp and retrieve rows as they were in that specific timestamp, just like you were used to do in Oracle:

```
(SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE AS OF TIMESTAMP ('13-SEP-04 8:50:58','DD-MON-YY HH24: MI: SS')
```

Equivalent query in SQL Server for a table with SYSTEM_VERSIONING=ON will be:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2004-09-01 08:50:58'
```

**To enable SYSTEM_VERSIONING for an existing table with rows you may use the following script**:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] ADD [SysStartTime] datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Inventory_SysStartTime DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00', [SysEndTime] datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Inventory_SysEndTime DEFAULT '9999-12-31 23:59:59', PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])  

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

After enabling SYSTEM_VERSIONING, the History table will show under the table where you enabled versioning:

[image]

**To Remove SYSTEM_VERSIONING from a table:**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);  

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME;  

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] DROP COLUMN [SysStartTime], [SysEndTime];
```

For more info you can visit the following link (or official Microsoft documentation referenced before):
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2016/147087/

Answer (score 2):

Closest equivalent is probably [Database Snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx). You can create a database snapshot at the moment of interest and then report against the snapshot. Unlike flashbacks, the moments at which the SQL Server snapshots are taken has to be pre-determined.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL server 2008 you can use  Change Data Capture, by this feature you can do a lot more than oracle flash back. (There is a store procedure to revert database on SQL server 2008 if you want i can provide that for you)

Comment: can you please provide stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, we can use [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) and [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server)
>   features which are Built in mechanisms in SQL Server and very much
>   similar to Flashback in Oracle.

When you apply Change Data Capture features on a database table, a mirror of the tracked table is created with the same column structure of the original table, but with additional columns that include the metadata used to summarize the nature of the change in the database table row.  The SQL Server DBA can then easily monitor the activity for the logged table using these new audit tables .

**Change tracking** is a lightweight solution that provides an efficient change tracking mechanism for applications. Typically, to enable applications to query for changes to data in a database and access information that is related to the changes, application developers had to implement custom change tracking mechanisms. Creating these mechanisms usually involved a lot of work and frequently involved using a combination of triggers, timestamp columns, new tables to store tracking information, and custom cleanup processes.

Different types of applications have different requirements for how much information they need about the changes. Applications can use change tracking to answer the following questions about the changes that have been made to a user table:

**What rows have changed for a user table?**

Only the fact that a row has changed is required, not how many times the row has changed or the values of any intermediate changes.

The latest data can be obtained directly from the table that is being tracked.

**Has a row changed?**

The fact that a row has changed and information about the change must be available and recorded at the time that the change was made in the same transaction.

For more information on how to use Change Data Capture (CDC) and Change Tracking in SQL Server; please check out [Pinal Dave's Post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/).

[image]

[Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 introduced [temporal tables aka history tables](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2016/create-sql-server-2016-temporal-table.aspx) which enables developers to query data stored in a database table in the past.

I mean developers can provide applications which enables users to display a table's historical data, or the view of a table at a certain time in the past